# a href(for button) not working on caraousel

Tags: php, html, jquery, css

> href is  not able to clickable on carousel due to jQuery

Carousel is using jQuery for automated sliding and when I'm placing an element with a `href` tag it's not working, also as the project is using multiple JavaScript files for fast uploading. I'm not able to identify how to make `href` clickable on carousel.
**How can I overwrite existing jQuery to make only that particular href clickable?**

```html
<li class="ds cover-image animated scaleAppear">
    <img src="<?php echo $Domain;?>img/slide2.jpg" alt="img">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="row  text-center" style="text-align:center;">
                    <div id="arrow-left" class="arrow">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 ">
                            <h6 id="firstLineh6"><span style="font-size:50px;">&#9632;</span>Farming-as-a-Service</h6>
                            <h1 id="firstLineh1">Advance,Affordable,<br>Accessible</h1>
                            <div class="vertical">
                                <p id="contP">
                                    We are making advanced farm mechanization services affordable to farmers through the
                                    Pay and Use Model
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <a id="carbtn1" href="https://google.com">Traxi Customer</a>
                            <a id="carbtn2" href="https://google.com">Traxi Partner</a>
                            <div class="col-sm-6 fade-in text-center" style="text-align:right;"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="intro_layers_wrapper">
                            <div class="intro_layers">
                                <!-- <div class="intro_layer">
                                    <p class="intro_before_featured_word pTextSize">Looking For Mechanized Crop Cultivation? </p>
                                    <p class="text-capitalize intro_featured_word pTextSize"> We are the "Solution" </p>
                                    <br>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $Domain; ?>products.php"  class="btn btn-outline-darkgrey big-btn font-25">Tell Us Your Farming Need</a> 
                                </div> -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Please try and create a [Minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Hey there as I got that your all links working with above code.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/akb88.jpg

But if you still facing issue with your Code you can try given below code for slider-

```css
.bs-fullscreen {
    height: 100%;
}
.bs-fullscreen .carousel,
.bs-fullscreen .item,
.bs-fullscreen .active {
    height: 100%;
}

.bs-fullscreen .carousel-inner {
    height: 100%;
}
.carousel-bg .carousel-inner .item {
    background-color: darkslategrey;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    min-height: 664px;
}

.banner-text {
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 215px;
    left: 12%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding: 47px 80px;
}
.banner-text p {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.banner-text h2 {
    font-size: 42px;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 44px;
}
.banner-text a {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 800;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
}
.banner-text span {
    font-size: 48px !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {
    .banner-text span {
        font-size: 34px !important;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width:400px) {
    .banner-text {
        position: center;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>
    <div class="bs-fullscreen">
        <div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide carousel-bg" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000">
            <!-- Bottom dots {indicators} -->

            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active"
                    style="background-image: url(https://www.ashleyandalvis.com/wp-content/uploads/4-3-1.jpg);">
                    <div class="banner-text">
                        <p>Eco Friendly | Feathery Light Perfect Fit</p>
                        <h2>50 WASH <br><span>UNDERWEARS</span></h2>
                        <a href="https://www.ashleyandalvis.com/shop/">Shop Collection</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item mob-banner"
                    style="background-image: url(https://www.ashleyandalvis.com/wp-content/uploads/Desktop-View-Home-Page-banner-1280x720px-1.jpg);">
                    <div class="banner-text">
                        <p>Memory Stretch | Skinny Soft Modal</p>
                        <h2>CONFIDENCE <br><span>INSIDE</span></h2>
                        <a href="https://www.ashleyandalvis.com/shop/">Shop Collection</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item mob-banner1"
                    style="background-image: url(https://www.ashleyandalvis.com/wp-content/uploads/Confidence-INSIDE-MOBILE-SLIDER-1280-%C3%97-720px.png);">
                    <div class="banner-text">
                        <p>Memory Stretch | Skinny Soft Modal</p>
                        <h2>CONFIDENCE <br><span>INSIDE</span></h2>
                        <a href="https://www.ashleyandalvis.com/shop/">Shop Collection</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope you like the answer.